# Netty putting concurrent requests on queue

Tags: java, server, netty

I have a problem with netty, I have a server with FutureChannel and Handlers

```
     ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyDecoder(service),new MyHander(),);

                    }

                })
```

I would like to  make this server to be single-threaded and put concurrent requests to queue, I know that it should be possible with proper dispatcher, but I am rather new with this and have no idea how to make this happen.
Thanks For Answering.

Comment: In what manner do you mean single-threaded? Full single threaded? Only your handler single threaded? Having a single server main thread?

Comment: I mean that  only one thread keeps handling requests, of course there may be another thread that will listen and put threads to queue.

Answer (score 3):

Making a single-threaded handler is simple.

You need to define another `EventLoopGroup` variable for this purpose, this variable will be our single-threaded exector group, so we set the thread-count to 1:

```
EventLoopGroup applicationGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
```

We can then use this group in our `ChannelInitializer` to schedule tasks on it, we use the [`addLast(EventExecutorGroup, ChannelHandler...)`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html#addLast(io.netty.util.concurrent.EventExecutorGroup,%20io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler...)) for this purpose:

```
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyDecoder(service))
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(applicationGroup, new MyHander());

                }

            })
```

After you constructed your pipeline using the separate `applicationGroup`, every request will come into it in a single-threaded manner, and that behaviour can be confirmed using simple debug statements. This method of construction has the advantage that you can simply assume one thread in the handler, while still doing the decoding of your protocol multithreaded and with high performance.

When you shutdown your server, you should make sure that you properly terminate the `applicationGroup`, like you are doing with your `workerGroup` and `bossgroup`

Comment: Thank You,
But will the concurrent request be put on queue ?

Comment: If the requests come in faster than the handler can process them, they will be put in a queue internal in netty, until there is time to process them, netty doesn't state anything about the order the requests come it, but you can be sure that `messageRecieved` is called before `connectionInactive`

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear about this. I don't exactly want just handler to be single threaded, I want in general one request processed at the time, others should be stacked in queue until all operations on this process are finished.

Comment: If you do the handling in the messagerecieved method of your handler, then you get the same result. remember that using queue is harder because you must also consider server stopping, while using netty it is done for you